# What does it mean Bootstrap is compiled?

Tags: frontend

I'm learning web-technologies and programming languages. Start learning about frameworks and other stuff. Looking at Bootstrap Front-End Framework. Some details I don't got about this thing.

On official web page it says you can download compiled and sources of Bootstrap. I don't get it, how can Front-End development be "source" and "compiled", ain't they just scripts that browser interprets?

Comment: Please accept the answer else add comment about your clarifications so that others can able to post answer for it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) uses [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) files to generate CSS files. The pre-compiled version contains the output from LESS. If you want to modify Bootstrap you'll need the source and then compile the LESS files into CSS.

The term compile is the word LESS uses on their website.

http://lesscss.org/

Doesn't it all compile in the browser upon page load? I'm guessing this means that it was compiled and tested before shipping, but I don't understand why this would need to be advertised.

No, Bootstrap can not run in the browser without the CSS being compiled using LESS.

Comment: "If you want to modify Bootstrap you'll need the source and then compile the LESS files into CSS" What is the problem in changing resulting Bootstrap CSS files?

Comment: A lot of people just use the bootstrap.min.css file and add their own stylessheet to it. This works when you’re trying to do something very quick (or don’t have a workflow set up), or when your modifications are minimal. The drawback of this is that you are totally reliant on Bootstrap’s HTML classes to make any modifications to your HTML, i.e. if you want to hide something at a certain media size, you have to use .hidden-lg, or if you were to set up a responsive section with different widths, your HTML would need to look like <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5 col-lg-6"></div>.

Answer (score 2):

From [Extending Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/extend.html):

> Bootstrap is made with LESS at its core, a dynamic stylesheet language
> created by our good friend, Alexis Sellier. It makes developing
> systems-based CSS faster, easier, and more fun.
>
> Since our CSS is written with Less and utilizes variables and mixins,
> it needs to be compiled for final production implementation. Here's
> how.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is written in LESS, a language that gets "processed" into CSS. It is common to use the word "compilation" to refer to this processing, as compilation is generally speaking the act of translating a language to another one.

Comment: So as get it right, if server has some additional interpreters for LESS, it will be works as a sources? Or interpreters must be installed at client-side?

Comment: Nope, LESS compilation only occurs as part of the development workflow. The browser never sees any less code, (nor does your web server probably). Consider it an helper for writing CSS.